# Set SlidingUpPanel Anchor Point Correctly in acitivity with Translucent Status Flag

Tags: android, sliding

My activity has a translucent status bar and I can't seem to get the anchor point right for the Umano Sliding Up Panel. What I want to achieve is still let the Sliding Up Panel slide up to right below the status bar. I know this is pretty easy in non-translucent-status-bar activity. But what about in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGOdh.png) a translucent-status-bar activity?

```
mLayout.setAnchorPoint((getScreenHeight()-getStatusBarHeight())/getScreenHeight(‌​));
}

public float getScreenHeight() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float height = metrics.heightPixels; return height;
}

public float getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3rjz.png)

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: mLayout.setAnchorPoint((getScreenHeight()-getStatusBarHeight())/getScreenHeight());
    }

    public float getScreenHeight() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float height = metrics.heightPixels;
        return height;
    }

    public float getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }

Comment: Hey sorry dude I'm quite a stack overflow newbie. Dunno how to format code here. Anyways my solution is I have two methods which respectively gets the window height and the status bar height. And then set "slidingUpPanelLayout.setAnchorPoint((screenHeight-statusBarHeight)/screenHeight);" Now the sliding up panel would overlap the status bar a little bit which is not an ideal solution.

Comment: you have an extra `}` in the code segment you put in the comments (which I copied to to the code).  Is this correct?

Comment: The extra bracket is the closing bracket for the onCreate() method. I don't think the rest of the code in it matters. I've also thought about setting and clearing the TRANSLUCENT_STATUS_FLAG dynamically in the onPanelExpanded() and onPanelCollapsed() methods but this is causing some problems too. The sliding panel does slide to the right position but the status bar would go wrong. The status bar would not become translucent which causes the activity window to be pushed down below the status bar.